# PowerShell equivalent of the C# "is" operator?

Tags: powershell

In a PowerShell script, I need to determine whether a .NET method call is actually returning the correct type of object, or at least a compatible type.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$a -is [string]
```

Or you can use GetType() and see whether the type is what you want.

Comment: @JaySullivan "powershell is operator" are great terms for it.

Comment: @jpmc26: Well yes, it is *now*, because when I search "powershell is operator" on Google, *this* Stackoverflow question is the first result.  None of the other search results are relevant.

Answer (score 6):

$yourObject.pstypenames will return the complete inheritance chain.